# How can I implement a hover event on a Xamarin.Forms button for MacOS and/or UWP?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, multiplatform

I have a Xamarin.Forms project that targets MacOS and WPF, amongst other platforms. For MacOS nad UWP I need to know when the mouse is hovering to button, in order to show a tool tip to the user. However the default Xamarin.Forms button [doesn't contain a MouseOver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.clicked?view=xamarin-forms) or something like that. I understand that this isn't a priority for mobile, but is there a way to achieve this for UWP and MacOS?

Do I have to use custom renderers, and if so, does anyone have a sample of a custom render for MacOS/UWP that could allow me to know when the mouse is hovering the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I implement a hover event on a Xamarin.Forms button for UWP?

For your requirement, you could use [Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating) to implement this feature.
At fist we need make `MouseOverEffect` and add `MouseOver` Action type attach property.

```cs
    public static class MouseOverEffect
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty MouseOverProperty =
    BindableProperty.CreateAttached("MouseOver", typeof(Action), typeof(MouseOverEffect), default(Action), propertyChanged: OnhandlerChanged);
    
    
        public static Action GetMouseOver(BindableObject view)
        {
            return (Action)view.GetValue(MouseOverProperty);
        }
    
    
        public static void SetMouseOver(BindableObject view, Action value)
        {
            view.SetValue(MouseOverProperty, value);
        }
    
        static void OnhandlerChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var view = bindable as View;
            if (view == null)
            {
                return;
            }
    
            Action action = (Action)newValue;
            if (action != null)
            {
                view.Effects.Add(new ControlTooltipEffect());
            }
            else
            {
                var toRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ControlTooltipEffect);
                if (toRemove != null)
                {
                    view.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
                }
            }
        }
    
        class ControlTooltipEffect : RoutingEffect
        {
            public ControlTooltipEffect() : base($"Microsoft.{nameof(MouseOverEffect)}")
            {
    
            }
        }
    }
```

**Then make IWP client Effect implementation**

Getting Attached button control and listen `PointerEntered` even, when pointer entered then invoke action method.

```cs
    [assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Microsoft")]
    [assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(UWPMouseEffect), nameof(MouseOverEffect))]
    namespace NavigateTest.UWP
    {
        public class UWPMouseEffect : PlatformEffect
        {
            protected override void OnAttached()
            {
                var control = Control ?? Container;
    
                if (control is FormsButton)
                {
                    control.PointerEntered += Control_PointerEntered;
                    
                }
            }
    
            private void Control_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
               var action =  MouseOverEffect.GetMouseOver(Element);
                action();
            }
    
            protected override void OnDetached()
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```xml
    <Button
        effect:MouseOverEffect.MouseOver="{Binding MouseOverAction}"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"
        Text="Next"
        />
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
    public class Page2ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        public Page2ViewModel()
        {
            MouseOver(() =>
            {
            // do some sth
    
            });
        }
        public Action MouseOverAction { set; get; }
        public void MouseOver(Action action)
        {
            MouseOverAction = action;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested it and it worked great. It also gave me some ideas on how to solve other issues.

Comment: This solution works great for me. We can add more event for control.PointerExited += Control_PointerMoved; to do something like hover the mouse pointer to a control to set background color for it then the background color will be reset when the mouse pointer is out